# Get large (original size image) in Picasa RSS feed

Tags: image, coldfusion, rss, picasa

I'm using a Picasa RSS feed no problem but I can't get the original large size image that I uploaded. When uploading via Picasa I purposely chose to upload 'Original size' (quite big).  The feed URL's only point to smaller images. How do I get the original big image from picasa?

I'm able to hack to URL from inspecting the image on the Picasa website so this is an example of the photo I want: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-yam9QV2NG40/ULKIMTKvQzI/AAAAAAAAAA4/ownr930MvGg/**s2048**/Blasket%2520Donkeys.jpg

I know that you can change the URL above with the s (bold bit above) in the URL.

So here's my coldfusion code to get and use the feed:

```
<cffeed name="picassa_RSS"source="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/104080781603408027307/albumid/5817402728494564577?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_US">

<cfoutput>
<!--- Loop through picasa RSS feed and output thumbnails --->
<cfloop array="#picassa_RSS.item#" index="i">
<img alt="img" src="#i.group.thumbnail[2].url#" class="picture">
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found the answer myself. See the imgmax parameter here:
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference#Parameters

You basically add **&imgmax=1600** to the end of the feed URL to get the largest possible size.

Answer (score 1):

Adding &imgmax=2048 to the url works for me as my images are 1920 width.