# Using span to edit an image

Tags: html, email, rss, gmail, mailchimp

I'm trying to edit my RSS feed email campaign in Mailchimp so that the images pulled from my blog are shrunk down to a usable size (540px). I use Squarespace, which unfortunately doesn't allow me to edit image sizes on the blog directly. Mailchimp insists on providing images at full size, so my RSS feed emails appear with 1500px wide images. I found some code that fixes the problem by using a style tag in Mailchimp:
 
`<style type="text/css">img,
.mcnTextContent,
.mcnTextContent img,
.mcnTextContent p,
.mcnTextContent p img,
.mcnTextContent a img {
max-width: 500px!important;
}`
However, Gmail doesn't recognize CSS and forces you to use inline tags. This makes an RSS email impossible, because I don't have an `img` tag to edit. I tried using a span to cover the text and images:
 `<span style="display:block; max-width:540px">*|RSSITEM:CONTENT_FULL|*</span>` 
 This worked on the text, but not on the images even though Gmail should support the max-width attribute: [Gmail compatible tags](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Any suggestions on how to make my RSS email format for Gmail would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get large (original size image) in Picasa RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672701/get-large-original-size-image-in-picasa-rss-feed)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I have the same problem now